# Read RFID Tag with Node.JS

Tags: node.js, rfid

I work on a project that uses the RFID Technology. I have bought an RFID Reader (http://www.idtronic-rfid.com/pdfs/01_BLUEBOX_2.0/UHF/BLUEBOX%20UHF%20Industrial%20Reader%20-%20CX%202CH.pdf) and an antenna.

All worked very correctly with the bluebox program. I manage to read RFID Tags.

But I want to read tags by a Node.js application.

The RFID reader is connect to my PC Windows 8.1 with an Ethernet cable.

This is my script for connect and to try to read RFID tags:

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '192.168.4.200';
var PORT = 3000;
var client = new net.Socket();

client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
 console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
});

//Read data
client.on('data', function(data) {

    console.log('DATA: ' + data);

});

// close event
client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

The connection work correctly because, when i connect to this port and IP via the BlueBox Software, the connection on the node.js server fails.

Now, I want to read RFID tags... But my function "data" is not perform... Do you have an idea please ?

Best Regards,

Comment: Interesting thing in conjunction with Node.js

Comment: Did you try to connect with Netcat? If not, try to connect to the device using Netcat and then see do you get any response.

Comment: I Download NetCat, put the command : nc -vv 192.168.4.200 3000, but the window close...

Comment: Use CMD to run Netcat if you are running Windows.

Comment: Can be useful: http://www.sans.org/security-resources/sec560/netcat_cheat_sheet_v1.pdf

Comment: This command : "nc -vv 192.168.4.200 3000" show this : inverse host lookup failed: h_errno 11004: NO_DATA <UNKOWN> [192.168.4.200] 3000 <?> open

Comment: Add exception to your firewall. Firewall is blocking you.

Comment: I have disable my firewall. With the same command, this is the same result

Comment: Try to scan your ports:
http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/11812-netcat-tips-and-tricks/

nc -v -w 2 192.168.4.200 -z 1-65535

Comment: But the problem isn't the connection with the RFID reader, it's the method for read on this. When I run my Node Js server, I have the log : "Connected to:192.168.4.200:3000" So it works. But i want to read the RFID Tags now... Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Mr D, I have the same issue..

Comment: Ok, connectio works fine (let us assume). Then, your data function is working it is performed, but you dont receive any data from device.

Comment: With the RFID Reader, I receive a documentation with an .exe. With this soft, I manage to read RFID tags. My goal now is read this RFID tags in my node.js application. So, I manage to connect on the RFID reader IP and Port, and now, i want to read RFID tags from reader... Do you understand me ?

Comment: I understand perfectly what is your problem. You connect but no data comming from device.

Comment: Yes, but the data comming with bluebox SDK. I want to find the method to do this in my node.js App !